# Reverse a Map which has A Set as its value using HOF

Tags: scala

I am trying to reverse a map that has a String as the key and a set of numbers as its value

My goal is to create a list that contains a tuple of a number and a list of strings that had the same number in the value set

I have this so far:

```
def flipMap(toFlip: Map[String, Set[Int]]): List[(Int, List[String])] = {
  toFlip.flatMap(_._2).map(x => (x, toFlip.keys.toList)).toList
}
```

but it is only assigning every String to every Int

```
val map = Map(
 "A" -> Set(1,2),
 "B" -> Set(2,3)
)
```

should produce:
`List((1, List(A)), (2, List(A, B)), (3, List(B)))`

but is producing:
`List((1, List(A, B)), (2, List(A, B)), (3, List(A, B)))`

Comment: You want `groupMap` after a `flatMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried replacing ```map``` with ```groupMap(identity)(identity)``` but am stuck here

Comment: First, construct a `List` of `(String, Int)` using `flatMap` & `map` from the original `Map`, then use `groupMap` to construct a `Map[Int, List[String]]` from that. Follow the types and the scaladoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works to, but it's not exactly what you might need and you may need some conversions to get the exact data type you need:

```scala
toFlip.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Set[String]]) {
    case (acc, (key, numbersSet)) =>
      numbersSet.foldLeft(acc) {
        (updatingMap, newNumber) =>
          updatingMap.updatedWith(newNumber) {
            case Some(existingSet) => Some(existingSet + key)
            case None => Some(Set(key))
          }
      }
  }
```

I used `Set` to avoid duplicate key insertions in the the inner List, and used `Map` for better look up instead of the outer List.

Comment: Thank You! I adapted it a bit by mapping it at the end and managed to finally get it :)

Comment: @JesséMonguar No problem! Also, you could've used List instead of Set and lookup if the value exists in the list or not, and manage wether to prepend the new value to it or not, but it costs to do such lookups in lists (O(n)), but Sets manage this more efficiently.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez completely right! I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```scala
def flipMap(toFlip: Map[String, Set[Int]]): List[(Int, List[String])] =
  toFlip
    .toList
    .flatMap {
      case (key, values) =>
        values.map(value => value -> key)
    }.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
    .view
    .mapValues(_.distinct)
    .toList
```

Note, I personally would return a `Map` instead of a `List`

---

Or if you have **cats** in scope.

```scala
def flipMap(toFlip: Map[String, Set[Int]]): Map[Int, Set[String]] =
  toFlip.view.flatMap {
    case (key, values) =>
      values.map(value => Map(value -> Set(key)))
  }.toList.combineAll
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// both scala2 & scala3
scala> map.flatten{ case(k, s) => s.map(v => (k, v)) }.groupMapReduce{ case(k, v) => v }{case(k, v) => List(k)}{ _ ++ _ }
val res0: Map[Int, List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(A), 2 -> List(A, B), 3 -> List(B))

// scala3 only
scala> map.flatten((k, s) => s.map(v => (k, v))).groupMapReduce((k, v) => v)((k, v) => List(k))( _ ++ _ )
val res1: Map[Int, List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(A), 2 -> List(A, B), 3 -> List(B))
```